# Nullable Types as Generics

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list for my personal library that can handle EVERYTHING. I'm trying to write it so that it can 'equally' easily hand `int`, `null`,`DateTime` or `Class` and I wanted it to be easily extendable, so that if I wanted to quickly make stack out of it, I can just write `push`, `pop`, and `peek` methods and so forth.

Currently, my code looks like this. Note that I use 'Base' as my generic type.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class LinkedList<Base> where Base : class
    {
        public class Node
        {
            private Node next;
            private Node prev;
            private Base value;

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for Nodes of Circular Linked List class.
            /// Calls overloaded constructor for no previous or next provided.
            /// O(1)
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value">The value to be stored. Can use tuple for associations</param>
            public Node(Base value)
            {
                    new Node(null, null, value);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for nodes of Circular Linked List class.
            /// O(1)
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="prev">The previous node in the linked list</param>
            /// <param name="next">The next node in the linked list</param>
            /// <param name="value">The value to be stored</param>
            public Node(Node prev, Node next, Base value)
            {
                this.prev = prev;
                this.next = next;
                this.value = value;
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the  'next' attribute of the node to the passed value.
            /// O(1)
            /// Chainable
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="next">The new value of the 'next' attribute.</param>
            /// <returns>Chainable(Node, this)</returns>
            public Node setNext(Node next)
            {
                this.next = next;
                return this;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the 'prev' attribute of the node to the passed value 
            /// O(1)
            /// Chainable
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="prev">The new value of the 'prev' attribute to denote the previous node</param>
            /// <returns>Chainable(Node, this)</returns>
            public Node setPrev(Node prev)
            {
                this.prev = prev;
                return this;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Changes the stored value of type Base to the passed value.
            /// O(1)
            /// Chainable
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value">The new value to be stored with the node</param>
            /// <returns>Chainable(Node, this)</returns>
            public Node setVal(Base value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                return this;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the next node in the linked list.
            /// O(1)
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>The next node in the linked list.(Node)</returns>
            public Node getNext()
            {
                return this.next;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the previous node in the linked list.
            /// O(1)
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>The previous node in the linked list.(Node)</returns>
            public Node getPrev()
            {
                return this.prev;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the value stored at this node.
            /// O(1)
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>The value stored at this node.(Base)</returns>
            public Base getVal()
            {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
        public Node head;
        public bool duplicates;
        public bool hasNullValues;
        public bool throwNullError;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the LinkedList. Creates a null head node.
        /// Duplication defaulted to false
        /// O(1)
        /// </summary>
        public LinkedList()
        {
            this.head = new Node(null);
            this.head.setNext(this.head).setPrev(this.head);
            this.duplicates = false;
            this.hasNullValues = false;
            this.throwNullError = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows duplication for the linked list.
        /// O(1)
        /// Chainable attribute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> hasDuplicates()
        {
            this.duplicates = true;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the structure to store null values in nodes.
        /// O(1)
        /// Chainable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> hasNulls()
        {
            this.hasNullValues = true;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Causes the structure to throw a null error when a null value is inserted.
        /// If hasNulls is off, turns it on.
        /// O(1)
        /// Chainable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> throwsNulls()
        {
            if (!this.hasNullValues)
            {
                this.hasNullValues = true;
            }
            this.throwNullError = true;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Iff duplicates not allowed, searches for value in list. Throws error if duplicate found.
        /// Creates a new node at the end of the list, then links it to the head node.
        /// O(length) [if hasDuplicates()]
        /// O(1) [if else]
        /// Chainable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value stored at the new node in the list</param>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> add(Base value)
        {
            if (!duplicates)
            {
                if (search(value) != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Value already exists in the linked list.");
                }
            }
            if (!this.hasNullValues && value != null)
            {
                if (this.throwNullError)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Cannot insert null values");
                }
                else
                {
                    return this;
                }
            }
            Node newNode = new Node(value);
            this.head.getPrev().setNext(newNode);
            this.head.setPrev(newNode);
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Iterates through the list until first such node for with a matching value is found.
        /// Returns null if no matches found. 
        /// Use searchAll to find duplicates. 
        /// O(length)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to be searched for.</param>
        /// <returns>First node with the desired value(Node?)</returns>
        public Node search(Base value)
        {
            Node temp = this.head.getNext();
            while (!temp.getVal().Equals(value))
            {
                if (temp.Equals(this.head))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            return temp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If value doesn't exist in the list, throws an exception.
        /// Deletes the first node found with the chosen value.
        /// Use DeleteAll to delete all instances.
        /// Chainable.
        /// O(length)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value to be removed from the list.</param>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> delete(Base value)
        {
            try{
                return delete(search(value));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new Exception("Node to be deleted not found");
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all pointers to the passed node.
        /// O(1)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tbd">The node to be deleted.</param>
        /// <returns>Chainable.(LinkedList<Base>, this)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Base> delete(Node tbd)
        {
            if (tbd.Equals(this.head))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot delete head node");
            }
            else
            {
                tbd.getPrev().setNext(tbd.getNext());
                tbd.getNext().setPrev(tbd.getPrev());
            }
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a LinkedList of all nodes containing the desired value.
        /// O(length)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to be found.</param>
        /// <returns>A LinkedList of Nodes with matching values.(LinkedList<Node>)</returns>
        public LinkedList<Node> searchAll(Base value)
        {
            LinkedList<Node> returnList = new LinkedList<Node>();
            Node temp = this.head.getNext();
            while (!temp.Equals(this.head))
            {
                if (temp.getVal().Equals(value))
                {
                    returnList.add(temp);
                }
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            return returnList;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the first Node in the Linked List.
        /// O()
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>First non-head node in the list.(Node)</returns>
        public Node firstOrDefault()
        {
            return this.head.getNext();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the value of the first node in the list.
        /// O(1)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>FIrst non-head </returns>
        public Base firstVal()
        {
            return this.head.getNext().getVal();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the last node in the linked list.
        /// O(1)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The last node in the linked list.(Node)</returns>
        public Node tail()
        {
            return this.head.getPrev();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the value of the last node in the linked list.
        /// O(1)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>VThe value of the tail node.(Base)</returns>
        public Base tailVal()
        {
            return this.head.getPrev().getVal();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            LinkedLis t<Int32> mine = new LinkedList<Int32>();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it gives Red Text under the `Int32`, saying "The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'Base' in the generic type or method ---this---.

Tell me if you would like me to remove the comments, I'm not sure if that makes it harder or easier to solve.

Comment: Isn't the `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` already doing most of all that? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You have declared a generic contraint, saying that all generic parameters must be reference types (`public class LinkedList<Base> where Base : class`)

Comment: Why do you have a constraint `where Base : class` if you want to handle value types (e.g. `int`)?

Comment: You should remove 95% of your code sample as basically one line is needed to show the problem `public class LinkedList<Base> where Base : class`. Basically if you see vertical scroll it is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you declared a constraint on a Base type to be a class (a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2(v=vs.80).aspx)):

```
public class LinkedList<Base> where Base : class
```

It exactly forbids using Int32, because it's a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and is [different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) from a required reference type.

```
new LinkedList<Int32>()
```

So, to fix this particular problem, you would need to to create a wrapper class for your integer values.

Before you do this though, check your intentions to store any type in your linked list. Doing so you will strip you off all advantages of C# as a strongly typed language.

And as it was mentioned before, unless you write this code as a pure academic exercise, you should use an existing .NET [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) and possibly extend/inherit it, if you need more functionality.

**Update:** I assumed it went without saying, but to make it crystal clear don't forget that [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) is a `struct`, not a `class`, so you cannot use "cheats" like  int?.